# boost jam: avoid toolset and variant in the build path

Tags: boost, bjam

when using boost jam to build a c++ project, the executable/library is in a path like

```
BUILD-DIR/SUBDIR/gcc-4.7.2/debug/EXEC_NAME
```

is there a way in the config file to get rid of the gcc-4.7.2/debug path for the executable?

thanks!

Comment: You can use `install` to copy the binaries to another location, see [Boost Installing](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/installing.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response! But I would need to install every exec/lib manually, right? And I would also need to manually specify the hierarchy, which I like to preserve, during install?